# Alpha beta Pruning implementation in matlab

Tags: matlab, recursion

I am continously getting an error while calling the following function. error is Output argument `bestboard` (and maybe others) not assigned during call to searchTree.m.

```
function [alpha,bestboard] = searchTree(board,depth,alpha,beta,turn)

if(depth<=0)

    alpha=calculateHeuristic(board,changeTurn(turn));
    bestboard=board;
    return
else
    child=GenerateChild(board,turn);
    a=size(child,3);

    if(turn==2)

        turn=changeTurn(turn);
        for i=1:a    
            [score,aboard]=searchTree(child(:,:,i),depth-1,alpha,beta,turn);
            if(score>alpha)
                alpha=score;
                bestboard=child(:,:,i);
            end
        end

        return
    else

        for j=1:a
            turn=changeTurn(turn);
            [scor,bboard]=searchTree(child(:,:,j),depth-1,alpha,beta,turn);
            if(scor<beta)
                beta=scor;
                bestboard=child(:,:,j);
                alpha=beta;
            end

        end

    return
    end
end
```

Comment: error is always in the recursive call to function...

Answer (score 3):

It's because `bestboard` is assigned in an `if` with no else. In your function, if `turn ~= 2` and `scor >= beta` and `depth > 0` then `bestboard` won't be assigned to. Consider assigning it a default value in the beginning perhaps?

Comment: No I can't code it, I don't know what your function is doing. All you need to do is make certain that `bestboard` is always assigned to, in the even that `turn ~= 2`, `scor >= beta` and `depth > 0`, what value would you like `bestboard` to have? Then simply add the line `bestboard = [insert your default value here]` to the first line of the function.